# Writing a file change listener in Ruby

Tags: ruby, directory, listener

I want to write a listener (ruby module) to identify a file creation inside a folder. My scenario is as follows

- I have a folder called (files)
- I have a Rails project which will create a file (demo.txt) inside
  the folder ('file')
- I need to write a listener to identify the file change and start
  reading the file (demo.txt)

Where can I start on creating this Ruby module?

I'm using 'Ruby 1.8.7 (2010-06-23 patchlevel 299) [i686-linux]'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few small libraries, which you could utilize, learn from or build upon, e.g.

- https://github.com/mynyml/watchr

> Agile development tool that monitors a directory tree, and triggers a user defined action whenever an observed file is modified. Its most typical use is continuous testing, and as such it is a more flexible alternative to autotest.

- http://codeforpeople.rubyforge.org/directory_watcher/

> The directory watcher operates by scanning a directory at some interval and generating a list of files based on a user supplied glob pattern. As the file list changes from one interval to the next, events are generated and dispatched to registered observers. Three types of events are supported — added, modified, and removed.

- https://github.com/guard/guard

> Guard is a command line tool to easily handle events on files modifications (FSEvent / Inotify / Polling support).

- http://rubydoc.info/gems/rb-inotify/0.8.6/frames

> This is a simple wrapper over the inotify Linux kernel subsystem for monitoring changes to files and directories. It uses the FFI gem to avoid having to compile a C extension.

Comment: Hi @miku, http://codeforpeople.rubyforge.org/directory_watcher/ seems to be a good option, thanks